# Websphere 8.5.5 UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: java, spring, encoding, utf-8, websphere

I have a problem with my application on *Websphere 8.5.5*. It's a spring rest application that is used to send email. In my service I receive the mail details and I use spring to forward it to the receivers. It works fine but when I try to send messages with non ascii character the message arrives with the special characters replaced by a question mark. The *UTF-8* encoding doesn't work. In my pc the application runs on Liberty Profile server and initially it doesn't work either. I googled the problem and found that spring needs a filter to interpret the special characters, so I added this lines to my 
*web.xml*

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>encoding</param-name>
          <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

On Liberty works fine but when I deploy the app on Websphere it doesn't.

I tried to directly translate the message in utf-8 with the String constructor:

```
new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")
```

and the same thing happens. It works on liberty but it doesn't on Websphere. 
Then I found that you can force WebSphere to use *UTF-8* by adding these JVM Arguments:

```
-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

like explained in this answer: 
[Character encoding issues on websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188694/character-encoding-issues-on-websphere)

I set the parameters on my server and restart like explained in many guides I found on the internet,
but obviously it didn't work.

This is the output of locale command in linux machine where WAS run:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I'am stuck and do not know what else to try.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `encoding.properties` file located at `<PROFILE_ROOT>/properties` is one more location that contains encoding settings. The default value (for English) is `en=ISO-8859-1`. Update this to `en=UTF-8` and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks i found the file, and as you say the value is `en=ISO-8859-1`. The problem now is that in the server run a lot of applications, that are hosted in different virtual servers. My application runs in a virtual server specifically created for her. Is that a way to set the `encoding.properties` at a single virtual server level? Because i don't want the changes to take effect on all the applications on server.

Comment: @amicoderozer : 1) Within the terminology of WAS, I'm not sure what you mean by the term 'virtual server'. Could you please clarify this? 2) ISO-8859-1 is a part of Unicode, so the global UTF-8 setting would not have any compatibility issues with your current applications.

Comment: I'm sorry my fault, i mean application server. I was wondering if i can set another encoding.properties file at application server level. ok thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: @amicoderozer : No problem. I've yet to see multiple servers defined under one profile, so I can't be specific about that use case. As the profile_root folder is shared across the servers, setting the encoding.properties file per server seems infeasible.