# ELK(elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filbeat for agent) Turkish character problem

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, turkish

I have ELK stack and I use filebeat for agent, I am logging by websphere log. However I have a problem about Turkish characters. Could anybody help me please on that issue?

```
[09.12.2019 12:05:42:848 EET] 00000150 SystemOut     O [ERROR] 
tr.com.cs.aurora.auroracore.utility.CSException: Genel sistem hatas�:
tr.com.cs.banking.corporatecredits.ccsutility.common.bean.exception.CCSRuntimeException at line 487
tr.com.cs.aurora.auroracore.utility.CSException: xxxxxxxxx numaral� m��teri i�in Kurumsal KKB sorgusu yap�lmad���ndan devam edilemiyor!
PRO_SME_GET_PC_SCORING_RESULT
tr.com.cs.banking.corporatecredits.ccsproposal.sme.services.ProSmePowerCurveService
getScoringResult
    at tr.com.cs.banking.corporatecredits.ccsproposal.proposal.services.ProFiaPointControlService.generateList(ProFiaPointControlService.java:407)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9069.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using UTF-8 encoding? Please see these two answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34013432/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38400986/

And welcome to Stack Overflow! :)